# Calling MoveFileEx under IIS

Tags: c#, .net, kernel, dllimport

I'm using this kind of code to remove file after system reboot.

**[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]

public static extern bool MoveFileEx(string lpExistingFileName,string pNewFileName,  MoveFileFlags dwFlags);**

Everything is ok with native iis-imitator in VS.
But when I'm using IIS this piece of code fails without any error message.

I can suggest that this is a problem with permissions on IIS.
But it's only my dumb suggestion.

Can you please help me with this case?

Answer (score 1):

- Check the return value of your call to `MoveFileEx()`. If it is false then the call failed.
- Call `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error` to find out the Win32 error code. This sometimes helps narrow the problem down (although not always).
- If that sheds no more light then you'll need to tell us the full path names for the file you are moving, and for its new destination.

---

In your comments you state that you are passing the `MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT` flag.  The [documentation for `MoveFileEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365240%28VS.85%29.aspx) states:

> This value can be used only if the process is in the context of a user who belongs to the administrators group or the LocalSystem account.

It seems likely that this is the root cause of the problem. Thanks to @Logan for pointing this out.

Comment: That means the process doesn't have sufficient rights to do it. Can you tell us the paths involved.

Comment: This is the path: C:\TempFiles\Test\Artur Okolity Test\Yo Preview 004\image.jpg. Btw, I'm calling this method with parameter: MoveFileFlags.DelayUntilReboot.

Comment: You need two paths to move a file. You've only given one.

Comment: DelayUntilReboot needs admin or LocalSystem